# Is it designed so that same badge have different shapes?

Tags: discussion, design, badges

I just got a new badge today on academia site, but the shape of the badge appear in different shapes when I am on different sites. If viewed from Mathematica site, it is **triangular shaped**

[image: mathematica]

however, if viewed from LaTeX site, it is **circular shaped**

[image: latex]

but it is the very same badge. Is this by design or not?